# What is HSQLDB(Hyper SQL) and how it differes from other DBs?

Tags: sql, hsqldb

Why we use HSQL with mybatis framework and how it differs from other DBs? Is this mandatory/preferred to use with Maven projects?

Answer (score 0):

Hyper SQL is [100% Java Database](http://hsqldb.org/)
From other DBs it differs by being written entirely in Java
No, it is not mandatory to be used with Maven projects.